# TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined - ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, parameters, use-effect

[image]

Please help me fix this. I couldn't figure out the issue.

Comment: props.match is coming as undefined. which is why its showing this error

Comment: Add your detailed code to the question or create a sandbox and share